# socket io connection working fine in localhost but not when deploying on heroku server

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

When I am running my code on localhost it is working fine but after deploying on heroku it shows error (GET Error)
Here Is My Code

Server Side Code

```
app = express()
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port..', app.get('port'));
});
var server = app.listen(4200);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
    console.log('connected..........');
})
```

Client Side Code

```
private socket = io('My-Heroku-server-address:4200');
```

Error

```
 https:My-Heroku-server-address:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MDpJszb
```

Comment: Others route work fine ?

Comment: yes..other routes are working fine

Comment: Check your red line error request, there is this one in header ? `no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Comment: no... "no-referrer-when-downgrade" no such thing in error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all.

Problem has been solved.

I just removed the port no.

```
    private socket = io('My-Heroku-server-address');
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the URL to connect in the client side code like `private socket = io('My-Heroku-server-address:4200');` just do

```
var socket = io();
```

This will try to connect to the host that serves the page.

Refer [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for more information.